# How to write on a circular path from inside

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been trying to write on a circular path. Everything is okay, but No way I can put it inside of the path, I mean the margin (path) will b on the top of the letters, and it will start from left to right. Like the veterinary on the margin(the margin is below) I want just the opposite for Pet hospital, but I cant make it.

Please help :'(

I tried every option  from Type on a path option, flipped even, but to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use alignment option Ascender. See the image:

[image]

You may want something like this.

[image]

Text Pet Hospital Co. has got baseline shift. It unfortunately needs also tracking adjustment to make it a little tighter.

Comment: Thank you, but you see there is gap between the margin and pet hospital? I dnt want any gap. I want  the letter below the margin without gap

Comment: @RussianBlue adjust the font position in the character panel

Comment: @joojaa where is position in character panel? I am crying :'( I cant fix it

Comment: Last item in the left column. Anyway the height of a font is sort of badly defined

Comment: @oneprivate no no, that is 0, that is ok, but look at the "veterinary'', see? how it sits without any gap? no space? I want same for ''pet hosputal'' from left to right, its not happening. ...

Comment: OHHHHH MY GAWWD!!! @joojaa yessssssss eysssssssssss... it wokred!!!  :O :O :O Thank you

Comment: :O :O :O :O :O.... I am too happy tht I wanna die in happiness. Thank you @joojaa